# GWT how to create ul li widget in UiBinder?

Tags: java, html, gwt, widget, uibinder

I would like to generate `<ul><li>` element in gwt. I wonder How to achieve this. Can Someone help?

I use gwt 2.7

**UiBinder code**

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder 
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    >


        <li ui:field="listItem" class="menu open">
            <m:MaterialLink ui:field="hyperlink" textColor="blue"></m:MaterialLink>
        </li>


</ui:UiBinder>
```

**Java code**

```
@UiField LIElement listItem;
```

**Console output**

```
[INFO] GET /recompile/cms
[INFO]    Job pl.daniel.cms.cms_1_69
[INFO]       starting job: pl.daniel.cms.cms_1_69
[INFO]       Compiling module pl.daniel.cms.cms
[INFO]          Computing all possible rebind results for 'pl.daniel.cms.client.ui.template.menu.GatekeeperProtectedMenuEntry.Binder'
[INFO]             Rebinding pl.daniel.cms.client.ui.template.menu.GatekeeperProtectedMenuEntry.Binder
[INFO]                Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Not allowed in an HTML context: <m:MaterialLink textColor='blue' ui:field='hyperlink'> (:12)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Errors in 'gen/pl/daniel/cms/client/ui/template/menu/com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java'
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 93: Failed to resolve 'pl.daniel.cms.client.ui.template.menu.GatekeeperProtectedMenuEntry.Binder' via deferred binding
[INFO]          Unification traversed 1505 fields and methods and 454 types. 7 are considered part of the current module and 7 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
[INFO]          [WARN] Some stale types ([pl.daniel.cms.client.ui.template.menu.GatekeeperProtectedMenuEntry_BinderImpl, pl.daniel.cms.client.ui.template.menu.GatekeeperProtectedMenuEntry_BinderImpl$Widgets]) were not reprocessed as was expected. This is either a compiler bug or a Generator has legitimately stopped creating these types.
[INFO]       [ERROR] Compiler returned false
[INFO]       [WARN] recompile failed
[INFO]       [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143286/1740724) answer?

Comment: Yes. But I would like to have widget inside that `li` element and I can not do this that way.

Comment: The answer places an `InlineHyperlink` inside the `li`, which is a widget.

Comment: Yes. But in my case I had a compilation error, saying that I cannot put widget inside `<li>` element. Strange. Can You explain me why I've got this error? What I did wrong?

Comment: Please add the `ui.xml` file content (or at least the relevant bits) to your question. The exact error would also be helpful.

Comment: Try making the root element a `<g:HTMLPanel>`.

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks man. Please put it into answer so I could close the post question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `HTMLPanel` as the root of your widget. `HTMLPanel` is the default, but it doesn't have to be `HTMLPanel`, it could also be a `FlowPanel` or something else.

So something like this will do:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder 
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:m='urn:import:gwt.material.design.client.ui'
>

<g:HTMLPanel>
    <li ui:field="listItem" class="menu open">
        <m:MaterialLink ui:field="hyperlink" textColor="blue"></m:MaterialLink>
    </li>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```